# Що таке ателічність?

Tags: значення-слів, існування-слова

На [ЛітАкценті](http://litakcent.com/2014/03/17/baljandrasy-nad-prirvoju/) читаю:

> Потім була постульована **ателічність** мистецького акту, а митець –
>   звільнений від відповідальності  за морально-філософські та
>   світоглядні наслідки свого творива.

СУМ-11, СУМ-20, англійсько-українські словники, російсько-українські словники (а там і Грінченко, і Єфремов з Кримським) цього слова не знають.

Ґуґл дає 4 результати. Жодний з результатів відповіді не дає.

Допоможіть, будь ласка, знайти значення цього слова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Телос](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telos) (від грецького *τέλος*) — кінець, мета, призначення (у досить вузькому сенсі цей термін використовується філософами, наприклад, Арістотелем).

Відповідно, ателічність — відсутність мети, призначення, замислу.

Ще цитата з [іншого джерела](http://www.ktm.ukma.edu.ua/show_content.php?id=1119):

> Іллєнко обирає для своєї «Доповідної» традиційну форму життєпису… <…> Також автор кількаразово апелює до постмодернізму. <…> Та якщо вже згадувати весь стандартний перелік ознак постмодернізму, то тут відсутня чи не головна – ателічність. В «Доповідній» телос не просто є – він, коли послуговуватися авторовим висловом, «стирчить» із кожного слова і речення. Ним, кінцевою метою й вихідним пунктом усього написаного і сказаного, є авторове «Я», забути про яке читачеві не дають навіть на один абзац.

<sub>Також є медичний термін [ателія](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F), що означає недорозвиненість (тобто від того ж *телос*, але вже зі значенням «недоведеність до кінця», а не «відсутність мети/призначення»). Хоча [деякі російські словники](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/6155/%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%AF) кажуть, що російське *ателия* може використовуватися і для позначення відсутності мети, тобто більш-менш аналогічно до *ателічність* (можливо, це стосується й українського *ателія*). В будь-якому разі, у вищенаведеному тексті явно мова про відсутність мети, а не про недорозвиненість.</sub>